# installing ffmpeg on MAMP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mamp, pecl, ln

I'm attempting to follow this tutorial: http://drupal.org/node/1464236 on installing ffmpeg on MAMP (for use with Drupal, which is incidental)

I'm stuck here:

*You should also execute in your Terminal*

```
which php pecl phpize
```

*which should point to your MAMP installation:*

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin
```

...but when I do it, `which php pecl phpize` says it's pointing to `/usr/bin/php` (and pecl and phpize respectively). If I do `ln /usr/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php` it says 'file already exists'. How do I point to the right file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$PATH` is wrong, which means that something went wrong in the first step of that tutorial:

> First of all point your php and phpize to your MAMP environment
>   Add/change following line in ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc (for bash):
>
> ```
>     export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/opt/local/bin
> ```
>
> and after that please re-login (or just execute e.g. /bin/bash).

Did you remember to re-login?

---

Let me also add, doing something like your attempted fix with `ln` is generally not a good idea.  `/usr/bin` generally contains system-installed software and may depend on that software being the correct version in the correct location.  If you want to use a different version of PHP for something, the standard practice is to install it somewhere else, like `/usr/local/bin`, and then have that directory listed before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`.  That way you'll use your version, while the system will still have its version to use.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what re-login means. I restarted terminal as well as MAMP. Was I supposed to restart something else?

Comment: @beth That should be enough.  If you `echo $PATH` are the MAMP directories at the beginning of the list?

Comment: Ach! No they're at the end. So I should move them to the front of the list?

Comment: @beth Yes you should.  Ordering is the name of the game when it comes to the `$PATH`.  In a nutshell, when you type `php` your shell is going to look at each directory in `$PATH` until it finds something executable called `php`.  If `/usr/bin` comes before the MAMP directory, it'll use the copy of php there.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
ls -l /usr/bin
```

If it shows something like `/usr/bin/php -> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin` in the last column you're all good. Otherwise, you might have to uninstall the non-MAMP php installation.

EDIT: You can also put the MAMP php path before /usr/bin in your $PATH. The first step in the linked tutorial tells you how to do that.

Comment: Removing system-installed software from `/usr/bin` is generally a bad idea as other parts of the system may well depend on having exactly that version of the software in exactly that location.